# Splitting Rails Javascript assets into head and body?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

What is the best way to split Javascript assets into scripts that need to load in the header and scripts that need to be in the body?

For instance, right now I have,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

At the end of my body tag in my main application layout. But I want to include something like,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application_head", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Inside my header tag.

How do I split my `application.js` into two separate files to accomplish this? Keep in mind that I need to be able to use direction likes `require_tree` in both files so I can't just include each script individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ mkdir app/assets/javascripts/application
$ mkdir app/assets/javascripts/application_head
```

copy stuff you want in the head into the application_head directory and the rest into application

app/assets/javascripts/application_head.js:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./application_head
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./application
```

in config/application.rb, add

```
config.assets.precompile << 'application_head.js'
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up omitting `require_self` and not splitting the javascript files into two directories.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how you'd manage this without splitting them if you're going to require_tree. If you require the entire javascripts directory in each manifest, won't that mean you've just got two versions of the same assets?

Comment: Only one of the scripts uses `require_tree`, in that file I used `stub` to make sure it didn't load the other sprockets file